# CSV file as a html table in a email body using Python

Tags: python, html

I need to read a CSV input file and send the CSV contents html table format in the email body. The CSV contains 5 columns and data of all 5 columns is either "success" or "failure".

Need to highlight the column "success" in green and "failure" in red color. I am able to send an email with html table format. But not able to do color coding based on CSV value.

Please do the needfull.

```
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTPException
import csv
from tabulate import tabulate
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib   

table = ''
with open('alert.csv') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    table = '<tr>{}</tr>'.format(''.join(['<td class="cell">{}</td>'.format(header) for header in reader.fieldnames]))
    for row in reader:
        table_row = '<tr>'
   #     #print(table)
        for fn in reader.fieldnames:

            table_row += '<td class="cell">{}</td>'.format(row[fn])
            table_row += '</tr>'
            table += table_row

html = """
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>html title</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
table{
    background-color: #000000;
    empty-cells:hide;
  Border:5px solid red;
 }
 td.cell{
    background-color: blue;
 }

</style>
</head>
<html><body><p>Hi!</p>
<p>Here is your data.</p>
<table style="border: black 0.5px;">
%s
</table>
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>Python 3.5</p>
</body></html>""" % table

message = MIMEMultipart(
    "alternative", None, [MIMEText(html,'html')])

message['Subject'] = "Some stats via mail"
message['From'] = 'donotreply@xxx.com'
message['To'] = 'pooja.kamat@xxx.com'

sender = "donotreply@xxx.com"
receivers = ['abc.def@xxx.com']
```

Comment: If u want to add color based on csv value u need to assign a color in style at the very point you are adding csv value in the table.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is simple to create two classes- one for Success and one for Failure, and then simply assign them to the cells. It's a little unclear what you mean by "highlight" since you're already filling the background color, but you should be able to adapt this easily enough.

*In the Style element*

```
/* Place after td.cell */
td.success {
    background-color: green; /* Highlight success as green */
}
td.failure {
    background-color: red; /* Highlight failure as red */
}
```

*During construction*

```
for fn in reader.fieldnames:
    ## row[fn] is expected to equal "success" or "failure"
    ## These are style classes (success=green, failure=red)
    ## If row[fn] is neither, it will be highlighted blue
    table_row += '<td class="{0} cell">{0}</td>'.format(row[fn])

## This should be de-indented (might have been copying error)
table_row += '</tr>'
table += table_row
```

Comment: Hi ... no need of background color . we can ignore that line. The csv table has either success or failure . Need to color it based on the value. i have tried the code as you mentioned but no luck . Got tuple index out of range error. Please do needful.     

        for fn in reader.fieldnames:
            table_row += '<td class="{}, cell">{}</td>'.format(row[fn])
        table_row += '</tr>'
        table += table_row

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to add the zeros into the String Formatting. I corrected it.